# Multiple/multiline commands (terminal command formatting) in chat don't work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

If I use (for example):

> Run `grun fishsticks` and then
>   `sudo breadcrumbs` in a terminal.

The system fails to render this correctly.

Instead it renders:

> Run `grun fishsticks` and then
>   `sudo breadcrumbs` in a terminal

Is this a known bug or by design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages). Multi-line messages have Markdown disabled.

Allowing multiline messages (with several restrictions, like this one) is there for, say, enabling pasting a log file in chat or some other kind of text.

What we *don't* want people to do is start using multiline for normal chatting. The purpose of chat messages is to be messages, and not walls-of-text.

That's why Markdown is disabled there: a) if you copy/paste something from somewhere, chances are it's *not* Markdown, and b) for discouraging the use of multiline messages for regular chatting.